# Tiger Geocoder - Postgres SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected with signal 11 segmentation fault

Tags: database, gis, postgis, geocoder, postgres-12

I'm using **r6g.4xlarge AWS** machine to test tiger geocoder of my own and succeeded in setting up the **Tiger Geocoder data of 2019** in a **postgresql version 12.** I've setup **pgtune** for better performance and made changes in the postgresql.conf file.

When I try to geocode some of the address I can able to get the solution with the latitude & longitude, But for some address I recieve error and postgresql service crashes and restarts again with an error **SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected** in the pgAdmin.

I tried to find the postgres log files and I can see that the crash happened with a message  **signal 11 segmentation fault**

My postgresql.conf has the following configuration from pgttune,

- max_connections = 200
- shared_buffers = 32GB
- work_mem = 41943kB
- maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
- effective_io_concurrency = 2
- max_worker_processes = 16
- max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 4
- max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4
- max_parallel_workers = 16
- wal_buffers = 16MB
- max_wal_size = 4GB
- min_wal_size = 1GB
- checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
- random_page_cost = 4
- effective_cache_size = 96GB
- default_statistics_target = 100

Comment: "Segmentation fault" indicates that either a) there is a PostgreSQL bug or a bug in an extension or b) you have data corruption or c) your hardware has problems. [Collect a stack trace](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Generating_a_stack_trace_of_a_PostgreSQL_backend) from the crash and add it to the question, that could help. Does the problem persist when you restart PostgreSQL?

Comment: I don't think there is a hardware or bug in extension. There can be data corruption, might be I'll reinstall the entire process and check whether the problem is still there

Comment: Sure, that would be interesting. Keep the original around if you want to get to the bottom of this.